# Number shaping for Bengali and Marathi in ibm icu library

Tags: java, java-8, websphere, java-11, icu

I wanted to know why the numbers are shaping (not displayed in Latin format) for Bengali and Marathi only as I tried for various other languages using **ibm.icu** library, refer below code and its result -

**Code** -

```
import com.ibm.icu.text.DateFormat;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public static void main() {

        final Locale english = new Locale("en", "IN");
        final Locale hindi = new Locale("hi", "IN");
        final Locale tamil = new Locale("ta", "IN");
        final Locale telugu = new Locale("te", "IN");
        final Locale kannada = new Locale("kn", "IN");
        final Locale malayalam = new Locale("ml", "IN");
        final Locale marathi = new Locale("mr", "IN");
        final Locale bengali = new Locale("bn", "IN");
        final Locale gujrati = new Locale("gu", "IN");

        Locale[] availableLocales = new Locale[]{english, hindi, tamil, telugu, kannada, malayalam, marathi, bengali, gujrati};

        for (Locale availableLocale : availableLocales) {
            System.out.println(availableLocale.getDisplayLanguage());
            printer(availableLocale);
            System.out.println("--------");
        }
    }


    private static void printer(final Locale locale) {
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getInstanceForSkeleton("EEEE, MMMM d, YYYY", locale);
        System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));
    }
```

**Result -**

```
English
Friday 19 March 2021
--------
Hindi
शुक्रवार, 19 मार्च 2021
--------
Tamil
வெள்ளி, 19 மார்ச், 2021
--------
Telugu
19, మార్చి 2021, శుక్రవారం
--------
Kannada
ಶುಕ್ರವಾರ, ಮಾರ್ಚ್ 19, 2021
--------
Malayalam
2021, മാർച്ച് 19, വെള്ളിയാഴ്‌ച
--------
Marathi
शुक्रवार, १९ मार्च, २०२१
--------
Bengali
শুক্রবার, ১৯ মার্চ, ২০২১
--------
Gujarati
શુક્રવાર, 19 માર્ચ, 2021
```

**Use case -**

- I want numbers to be displayed in Latin format only for all languages.

**Query -**

- How this can be fixed?
- Why numbers are not formatted in latin format for these locales?

Answer (score 0):

You can force Latin digits by creating your Locales with the [standard Unicode extension](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Key_Type_Definitions) `nu`, whose standard values include `latn`.  I don’t know if it works in the ibm.icu library, but I know that this works with [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
final Locale english = Locale.forLanguageTag("en-IN-u-nu-latn");
final Locale hindi = Locale.forLanguageTag("hi-IN-u-nu-latn");
final Locale tamil = Locale.forLanguageTag("ta-IN-u-nu-latn");
final Locale telugu = Locale.forLanguageTag("te-IN-u-nu-latn");
final Locale kannada = Locale.forLanguageTag("kn-IN-u-nu-latn");
final Locale malayalam = Locale.forLanguageTag("ml-IN-u-nu-latn");
final Locale marathi = Locale.forLanguageTag("mr-IN-u-nu-latn");
final Locale bengali = Locale.forLanguageTag("bn-IN-u-nu-latn");
final Locale gujrati = Locale.forLanguageTag("gu-IN-u-nu-latn");
```

Comment: Thanks VGR@ for the suggestion, I'll try the solution and inform you and if you know can you please inform, what is the reason why numbers are not formatted in latin format?

Comment: I don’t know.  I assume each locale is based on the prevalent cultural practices in the corresponding region.  [The CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org) site has a lot of documentation on their decisions.